# html <sub>, <i> inserting tab (or other space)

Tags: html

The following code outputs extra space in front of each respective, `<i>` and `<sub>`.  True on local server and published online.  Note:  the space does NOT get maintained when I copy-and-paste from my screen.  How do I fix this?  thanks!

```
<p>We will <i>call</i> the missing endpoint (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>).</p>
```

output:
We will [long space is here] call the missing endpoint (x [long space] 2, y [long space] 2).

Comment: Check the CSS applied to these elements via a web inspector.

Comment: Not showing extra spaces here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/33mavdv1/
My guess is you have CSS applying to those elements, please provide a more full example or a link to the site.

Comment: HTML does not ignore a single white space, but it converts more than one space or HTML line break to a single white space. Maybe your initial code is breaking lines before `<i>` and `<sub>`. That is my guess. Get rid of those breaks in your source code.